# How do we save the changes made by user in onPause()

Tags: android

When an activity is being killed, onSaveInstanceState() is used to save the state of the activity, and the returned bundle is passed to onCreate() when the activity is created again. 
When an activity is paused, we also persist any changes which need to be saved in case the user leaves the activity. How do we do that? Is that also done by calling onSaveInstanceState() and then the returned bundle is passed to onResume()?

In a nutshell, how is the state of an activity in the paused state persisted? How are any changes made by the user persisted/saved while the activity is paused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hope my question is clear. I mean calling the onSaveInstanceState() is the mechanism of saving the activity's current state is the mechanism used in onStop() if I am not wrong.

What is the mechanism used in onPause() to save an activity's current state, which will be resumed when onResume() will be called?

Comment: you have confusing `onSavedInstanceState()` with **Activity** *Life Cycle*, refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: There was an answer right here which said something like I don't need to do this in onPause() and I had to reload this page due to some reason, and its gone. I don't know where it is gone. I am confused.

Comment: you don't need to presist state in onPause(), because when the activity process is alive your activity state and resources are saved in memory, but when Android System kills the process to reclaim memory for some other activity then `onSavedInstanceState()` is called to give you a chance to save the data so you can presist it during `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` or `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: check out Activity Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: I have seen this reference. It itself says that onSaveInstanceState() is used to retreive per instance state of an activity before it is killed. 
But we also commit unsaved changes (reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) in onPause() assuming that the user will leave the activity. How do we commit these unsaved changes in onPause(). That is what I want to ask.

Comment: Well for this kind of scenario depending on your application requirement you can use `SharedPrefrences` or `Local Database(i.e SQLite)`

Comment: "because when the activity process is alive your activity state and resources are saved in memory" 
It means that our activity is alive, all the actions (e.g. a video playing) are just paused, its nothing different from the running/resumed state except that the on-going actions which would consume CPU will be stopped.
Am I right?

Comment: For example, if the activity enters the paused state when the user was composing email. The user expects the draft email to be saved even if they leave the activity. so the draft email needs to committed, I don't thing the local database etc. will be used to save that partially composed email.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` or SQLite.

Comment: Yes Activity is Alive the references to `VideoView` are also alive. but you need to manually pause the video else it will play in background. `onPause()` just tell the system that activity is going in background.

Comment: for email draft example, you can use `SharedPreferences`